# Appsync query type returning multiple individual types

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I'm new to Appsync and stuck with the following

```
type User{
    id: ID
    name : String
    address: String
}

type Car{
    id: ID
    model: String
    make: String
}

type Query {    
    getusers: [User]    
    getcars: [Car]
}
```

This works fine as getusers and getcars have the two different HTTP endpoint set as data source.

What i'm trying to do is create another type **AllDetail** and query **getdetails** (expecting to return list of all users followed by list of all cars)

```
type AllDetail{
    users : [User]
    cars : [Car]
}
type Query {    
    getusers: [User]    
    getcars: [Car]
    getdetails : AllDetail
}
```

I need help in 
1) setting up the data source for getdetails (since it involves two endpoints)
2) is there any other means to make getdetails return list of all users followed by list of all cars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, there is no relationship between users and cars in you schema.

I would then simply put a resolver for users in AllDetails type and an other one for cars.
[image: Both type resolvers]
In the console, you can get some standards resolvers that will fit your need to get all cars and all users (List Items).

Then on the query, I would add a pipeline resolver with simply the after mapping template.

[image]

```
type Both {
    events: [Event]
    comments: [Comment]
}
[...]
type Query {
    listBoth: Both
}
```

I tested it successfully.

Comment: Thank you very much. Cheers !